# Unit test exception when calling class library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

Unit test exception when calling class library

When I use Winforms to call a log4net log output class library, it runs normally, but when I use UnitTest for testing, Visual Studio reports an error:

```
 [TestClass]
 public class UnitTest1
 {
   [TestMethod]
   public void TestMethod1()
   {

      log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

      TestClass te = new TestClass();
      te.TestLog();
   }
 }
```

Error content:

```
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'log4net.Util.SystemInfo' threw an exception.
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Am I missing something, I need some help

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first error, you need to register a type with the configuration section:

```
<config Sections>
     <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
   </configSections>
```

For the second error, you need to run the following command in the NuGet package manager to resolve this issue:

```
Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
```